# onPrepareOptionsMenu android app

Tags: android

I am trying to use the onPrepareOptionsMenu and when I press the menu, it does nothing!! Where am I going wrong?

Also, am I using the finish (); command right? When the user presses exit(menuX) I want them to exit the application completely, not the activity.

Thanks! :)

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
MenuInflater getItnow = getMenuInflater();
getItnow.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
return true;
}

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.menuA:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.abc.example.A"));
        return true;
    case R.id.menuB:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.abc.example.B"));
        return true;
    case R.id.menuC:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.abc.example.C"));
        return true;
    case R.id.menuD:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.abc.example.D"));
    case R.id.menuX:
        finish();
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all I would rather use `onOptionsItemSelected` then `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. Because as I understand you just want to press it. It is quite the same only first line is changed.

The second thing - app exit. Well, if this menu is in your main and first activity, then when you call `finish()` then this activity is destroyed (not exactly but the thing is that you don't see it anymore), so if app has no more activity everything is destroyed.

More advanced method for that is using instruction `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` and what it is doing is simply sending kill signal for whole process. As far as your app won`t get bigger, I mean you will have only your activities in this process, than it is fine. Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi sebap,

 I just edited my code and it does work. however, the code you provided me (killProcess) does not work. It takes me back to the first screen. I have so many classes and everything, so I am pretty sure my code is flakey :(. 

Also onOptionsItemSelected places the menu at the top right. WHat option places it at the bottom screen? I am testing this on a tablet (not phone) so I could be seeing different things.

Comment: try System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
System.exit(0); to kill the app

Comment: @MCarter About process kiling I have no, or maybe quite small idea, what is wrong. The fist thing is that, mayby you are opening new processes or "jumping" between them. Second thing is to close every unused activity when you are leaving activity (for example when you send resources from activity called for result) then in onStop call finish(). The you will be sure that it is "dead". Now I have no idea about menu. Are you using method which Wookie posted?

Comment: ugh! I must have bad coding, because it took me to the previous activity. :( oh wow. I suck...I thought I was doing good too. :(

Comment: @sebap123 I am not using the method Wookie posted because I do not even know where to begin. the following code branches off of a different activity. So We have the Main class > Location class > Location A class. Location A when exited brings up Location. So it is taking me back not quitting the application.

Comment: past mayby some code (I mean some more) on pastebin.com with commenst what you exactly want to happen and I will try to help you.

Comment: @sebap123 thanks so much! I am still having issues though exiting the app entirely from the LOCATIONA. It still takes me to LOCATION. 

also, why is it a good idea to not include XML? thanks for all your help. I really appriecate it.

Comment: Well, I have no more good ideas about closing app. Why it is good to not include menu into XML. I think that it is easier at the beginer level and also you make Android do all staff for you, so you don't have to think about it. If you have got everything in XML then you can make it more custome but you have to know more about it. No problem this site is Q&A site. Today I helped you, tomorrow maybe you will help me.

Comment: cool. gotcha. I probably will not bother worrying about exiting the app..it's not a big deal. closing the app never really closes the app because it will always be shown as a screenshot. so would you suggest that I go away with XML? are the advance apps XML or just java-based? thanks for all the positive energy :)

Comment: you know what I was just thinking...could I possibly create a class just for this menu? menu a - x? that way, I could do extends menudrop or something like that...would that be a bad idea?

Comment: You shouldn't kill the process - it's up to the system to decide when the process can be safely terminated. That's how Android works.

Answer (score 1):

When I create an options menu, I usually use these two methods:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "option text");
            .....
    }
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    if(item.getItemId() == 1)
    ...
}
```

Also, with your switch statement, you are forgetting to put in break; for each option (which I notice mostly because I am notorious for doing the same).

Comment: how would I put in break wookie? could you please show an example using my code? I am sorry, but I am soo terribly new to this and I need step by step. :(

Comment: The best would be if you would have first definition - `private static final int MENU_A = 1;`, in onCreateOptionsMenu somethink like: `menu.add(0, MENU_A, 1, "Menu A");` and in onOptionItemSelected switch(item.getItemId()) - I think it is better. Then for example `case 1: startActivity(new Intent("com.abc.example.A"));break;` and that's all.

Read [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) - on of the best you descriptions you can find.

Comment: where would I put     private static final int MENU_A = 1?